# Create Demo watch on wrist without tracker

Tags: unity-game-engine, mapping, augmented-reality, tracking, vuforia

I'm looking for a solution. I'm aware of  3d tracking with programmes like Vuforia because
I want to build an app to demo watches on the wrist. However I don't want to use any trackers on the hand. Is there a way to use marker-less tracking on my wrist to achieve the same experience

I want to create AR app that can try watch on wrist without using any tracker

Comment: Your question kinda reads as _["where they want to start, and where they want to end, but there are way too many pieces to fill in"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/223458/284550)_ and if so might be considered too broad.  Consider adding more information about how you would like your problem solved, perhaps with a code sample of what you have already tried.  Good luck!

Comment: For now, I just focus on the 3d model first but I don't know how to track the wrist but did not know how to track it. From what I researched right now, I find something called hand mapping and tracking but still did not know how to do it. Here is the link [link](https://www.perfectcorp.com/business/products/ar-watch). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try [MediaPipe Hands](https://google.github.io/mediapipe/solutions/hands.html) from Google. There is an open-source [MediaPipe Plugin](https://github.com/homuler/MediaPipeUnityPlugin) for Unity as well.

Comment: Is the function of media pipe the same as vuforia when I want track the image/object target?

Comment: I am not familiar with Vuforia. Did you read about MediaPipe? Not sure what you mean by "image/object target"  but it sounds from the question like you are tracking the hands--MediaPipe will let you do markerless tracking on the hands.